# Cartoon Style Materials and Render

Tags: rendering

First post here and I am trying to determine what I would need to do (or try to do) to create a static render that looks more like the 3D cartoons I watch with my kids than a semi-photorealistic render.  I am so much more interested in the 3D cartoons than realistic renders but I just can't figure out how to make my images look like a cartoon similar to an image like this (below).[image: cartoon]

My renders (which are not great since I am a relative beginner) always end up looking something like this (below).[image: my render]

I am not an artist so I may not have the eye for this but my gut feeling is that the cartoon style has more hand-drawn textures.  Perhaps it is more the lighting.  Can anybody give me some hints as to how I could move towards this 3D cartoon style of modeling and rendering rather than the sort of realistic look?

Here is another screenshot of the kind of render I am hoping to one day achieve.  I can imagine that some of the textures are procedural node-based, ie. seat on tractor.  But what is it about this image that makes it look more like a 3D cartoon than some kind of photo-realistic image?
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello and welcome This looks like a primarily subjective question, your renders look fine to me. Which part are you unsatisfied with? Could you edit your question and make it more concise? Perhaps focus a bit on the technical side of the problem.